# Visual tool for browsing LMDB files

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I am looking for a program that works on Mac OS X 10.10 and can open and display an LMDB file ([Lightning Memory-Mapped Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Memory-Mapped_Database)). Ideally, gratis, can also edit the file, and supports large files, like [HDFView](https://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/) for HDF4 and HDF5 files.

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.